# Google Analytics: updating multiple accounts

Tags: google-analytics

I have account that has 100 accounts, I've added a Google Service account (I can't use anything else because of 3rd party app limitation) and now I need to allow it to access all of these accounts. Seems there's no way at Google Analytics UI to do that and I will have to manually edit 100 accounts.

Is there any better way to do it? Maybe something like AdWords Editor just for Analytics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Google User Account that has access to all the Google Analytics Accounts (which is how I interpret your first sentence) you can bulk edit them via the [Google Analytics Management API, and that includes adding users](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountUserLinks/insert) that might or might not be service accounts. A reasonable easy way would be to use a Google Spreadsheet and some [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/). The script will run as the user that is currently logged in to Google and will be able to access all Analytics account that user has access to.

However you need to have necessary permissions to edit the GA accounts, so if you do not already have an authorized account you will (unsurprisingly) not be able to add one

Comment: Thanks! This helped a lot. I've managed to make all my changes using just single Google Script.